# auto generated purchase order number base from year in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code which should generate purchase number automatically with year attached to the number.

```
$record = Ponumbers::latest()->first();
    $expNum = explode('-', $record->purchase_num);
    //check first day in a year
    if ( date('l',strtotime(date('Y-01-01'))) ){
        $nextPoNumber = 'po'.date('Y').'-000001';
    } else {
        //increase 1 with last invoice number
        $nextPoNumber = $expNum[0].'-'. $expNum[1]+1;
    }
```

but it doesn't seems to work because it display only the this,
[image]

I am guessing it only displayed what's in this line

```
$nextPoNumber = 'po'.date('Y').'-000001';
```

any suggestion? thanks you so much in advance!

Comment: What should it be displaying?

Comment: hi @GeorgeHanson. it should display the incremented value from the purchase number table. for example the last record is po2019-000001, it should display po2019-000002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date('l',strtotime(date('Y-01-01')))` returns first weekday name for 2019, which is `Tuesday`. That is truthy value so the `if` is always true and `$nextPoNumber` is always `po2019-000001`.

If I understand your code correctly this is what you like it to do:

```
$record = Ponumbers::latest()->first();
$expNum = explode('-', $record->purchase_num);
$nextPoNumber = 'po'.date('Y').'-'.sprintf("%06d",$expNum[1]+1);
```

Comment: hi @Azur! thank you for responding. I tried that already. it only display "1" in the input box

Comment: yes it does! thanks a lot! may I know what this means, sprintf("%06d" ? I am trying to understand  it :)

Comment: It does the zero filling, `1` comes to `000001` or `958` comes to `000958`

Comment: ahhh and how about the 6d? is it the number of digit ?

Comment: Yes, it's well explained in documentation and you can find many more examples also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: thank you so much @AzurInspire! I really appreciate your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$record = Ponumbers::latest()->first();
$expNum = explode('-', $record->purchase_num);
//check first day in a year
$first_day = gmdate('j', strtotime('first day of january this year'));
if (date('j') == $first_day){
    $nextPoNumber = 'po'.date('Y').'-000001';
} else {
    //increase 1 with last invoice number
    $nextPoNumber = $expNum[0].'-'. $expNum[1]+1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MohammedAZOUZ! this works too! I guess this is the best answer because it has a condition to start in 000001 after new year. but I replace . $expNum[1]+1;  with .sprintf("%06d",$expNum[1]+1); from @AzurInspire answer. It is working now. Thanks!

Comment: But this will give `po2019-000001` as purchase order number to all orders which are done in first day of the year. And if there isn't any orders in 1st of January the orders for rest of the year will have past year in their purchase order number. Of course if there is one and only one order every single day then this works fine.